# TYPO3: Special tt_contenttype. Modify content before output

Tags: typo3

Can I create a "special" type of tt_content, so text is beeing processed in some custom ways before outputtet?

In my case  I would like to add ###MY_MARKER### somewhere in header and/or bodytext and have it replaced by the right words for the given page.

eg:

- When visiting this page: mypage.com/?marker=test
- Header in tt_content: "Welcome to ###MY_MARKER##, enjoy
- Output in browser: "Welcome to TEST, enjoy"

I CAN do it by making a custom plugin. Question is more if I can reuse normal tt_contant for the same purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can easily extend the `tt_content` by adding your own **TCA** configuration to the **typo3conf/extTables.php** file:

```
t3lib_div::loadTCA('tt_content');

$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['CType']['config']['items']['user_my_type'] = array(
  0 => 'My custom content',
  1 => 'user_my_type',
  2 => 'i/tt_content.gif',
);
$TCA['tt_content']['ctrl']['typeicon_classes']['user_my_type'] = 'mimetypes-x-content-text';
$TCA['tt_content']['ctrl']['typeicons']['user_my_type'] = 'tt_content.gif';

/* In the following either copy, insert and modify configuration from some other
   content elemenet (you can find it in the ADMIN TOOLS -> Configuration - $TCA)... */
$TCA['tt_content']['types']['user_my_type']['showitem'] = '';

/* ...or assign it some other configuration so that it's exactly the same
   as some other content type and stays the same after some update of TYPO3: */
$TCA['tt_content']['types']['user_my_type']['showitem'] = $TCA['tt_content']['types']['text']['showitem'];
```

After that, just set in your Typoscript template how the element is supposed to be rendered:

```
tt_content.user_my_type = COA
tt_content.user_my_type {
  10 = TEMPLATE
  10 {
    template = TEXT
    template.field = header

    marks {
      MY_MARKER = TEXT
      MY_MARKER.value = TEST
    }
  }

  20 = TEMPLATE
  20 {
    template = TEXT
    template {
      field = bodytext
      required = 1
      parseFunc = < lib.parseFunc_RTE
    }

    marks < tt_content.user_my_type.10.marks
  }
}
```

### NOTES

1. The Typoscript rendering is just a simplified example. You might want to add other standard configuration like in other elements, e.g. the one that adds edit icons for frontend display.
2. The marker in my example can be populated by the value of a GET paramater in the URL as you wanted but this would have nasty security implications. You would certainly need very good validation of that input.

Comment: Thank you for this great tutorial. First part works just fine. For the rendering I think of using php since I don't know other way. But I only need to substitute a ###MARKER### in header and bodytext before rendering the tt_content element. Can that be done with typoscript? Else I will make a class.user_my_type.php to do it for me. Thanks again

Comment: I think you should be able to easily do it with standard Typoscript features. 2 options for replacing come to my mind though I never used any of them for this. FIRST option is to try to use the good old **[TEMPLATE](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Template/Index.html)** object. You can try to populate its `template` property with the text that the user filled in (bodytext or header field) and set the `marks` property as replacements. Note that for the bodytext you would first have to apply all standard tranformations. See `tt_content.text` to find out how.

Comment: SECOND option is to use more current (TYPO3 >=4.6) **[replacement](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Replacement/Index.html#replacement)** property of **[stdWrap](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html)**. You would basically copy the config for `tt_content.text` and add `stdWrap` with `replacement` to the *header* and *bodytext* fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will play around wioth it and start a new question about the way to do it with php.

Comment: I've added the FIRST option as an example to my answer.